# Using Lock and Rlock in the same go routine

Tags: go, goroutine

I am working in an experiment using RWMutex in Go, and I realized that is possible to have this behavior with the follow code:

- goroutine 1 - RLock
- goroutine 1 - RUnlock
- goroutine 2 - RLock
- goroutine 2 - RUnlock
- goroutine 2 - Lock
- goroutine 2 - Unlock
- goroutine 1 - Lock
- goroutine 1 - Unlock

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type RLockAndLockStruct struct {
    mu sync.RWMutex

    mapEx map[string]string
}

func main() {
    r := &RLockAndLockStruct{}
    r.mapEx = make(map[string]string)

    go r.RLockAndLockTest("test", "goroutine 1 - ")
    go r.RLockAndLockTest("test", "goroutine 2 - ")
    time.Sleep(4000 * time.Millisecond)
}

func (r *RLockAndLockStruct) RLockAndLockTest(value string, goroutine string) string {
    r.mu.RLock()
    fmt.Printf("%sRLock\n", goroutine)
    t := r.mapEx[value]
    r.mu.RUnlock()
    fmt.Printf("%sRUnlock\n", goroutine)
    if len(t) <= 0 {
        time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
        r.mu.Lock()
        fmt.Printf("%sLock\n", goroutine)
        r.mapEx[value] = value
        r.mu.Unlock()
        fmt.Printf("%sUnlock\n", goroutine)
        return r.mapEx[value]
    }
    return t
}
```

I have read in some articles that the correct way to use map in Goroutines is using RWMutex with RLock to read and Lock to write. However, as you can see in the code above, if two Goroutines starts almost in the same time, it is possible to have two writes in the same map instead of one write and one read.

From that, I have some questions here:

1. Is there a way that we can guarantee just one goroutine writing on a map (entering the if codeblock above)  and all other routines reading that map with the new value (avoid entering the if codeblock)?
2. Is it the correct implementation for goroutine and maps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because your code has a race condition in it. You read-lock the map to read it, make a decision, and then write-lock it. There is no guarantee that when you get the write lock, the condition you made the decision on still holds.

The correct way would be to retest the condition after locking:

```
    if len(t) <= 0 {
        time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
        r.mu.Lock()
        if len(r.mapEx[value])<=0 {
          fmt.Printf("%sLock\n", goroutine)
          r.mapEx[value] = value
        }
        r.mu.Unlock()
        return value
```

Note the use of `return value` above, because otherwise it would have to access the map again.

Comment: I think still there can be a concurrency issue because of `return r.mapEx[value]`.

Comment: @nipuna, good catch, I added that to the answer

Comment: Sure, then it will be perfect :-)

Comment: Intead of returning value, could we use: `r.mu.RLock(); t2 := r.mapEx[value]; r.mu.RUnlock(); return t2` After `r.mu.Unlock()`?

Comment: Yes, but what's the benefit of that? Ideally, you wold do `r.mu.Lock(); defer r.mu.Unlock()`, and then return the value, letting defer take care of the unlock. Note that once the function returns, the value is already stale. There is no guarantee that after the function returns another goroutine didn't change the value.